# How to restrict admin access to specific store on same installation?

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9, admin, backend, permissions

How can I restrict admin access to specific store? For example:

Admin A
Admin B
Admin C

Store 1
Store 2
Store 2

Admin A > Store 1
Admin B > Store 2
Admin C > Store 3

I know there are some paid modules on Magento Connect, but I would like to find another solution.

All these stores are in the same Magento Installation.